# CSS Missing right border in tableless coding

Tags: css

I have created a CSS 2-column page without the use of tables. Within each column, I want to display boxes in these columns, again without the use of a table. I am able to create the 2 columns and boxes within each column but the issue is, within each box, the right border is missing. Here is a screenshot showing the [issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOv0K.jpg):

What is wrong with the code? How do I display the border on the right using tableless coding and valid markups? Here are the codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>box-in-columns</title>
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
body {
background:#FDEDF2;
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
font-size: 9pt;
}
#header h1, #header h2, #header p {
margin-left:2%;
padding-right:2%;
}
#footer {
clear:both;
float:left;
width:100%;
}
#footer p {
margin-left:2%;
padding-right:2%;
}
#container2 {
clear:left;
float:left;
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
background:#FDEDF2;
}
#container1 {
float:left;
width:100%;
position:relative;
right:50%;
background:#FDEDF2; 
}
#col1 {
float:left;
width:46%;
position:relative;
left:52%;
overflow:hidden; 
}
#col2 {
float:left;
width:46%;
position:relative;
left:56%;
overflow:hidden;
}
#table {
display:table;
width:100%;
margin:0;
padding:4px;
border:1px solid #607080;  
background:#FFFFFF;
}
.row-header {
display:table-row;
color: #b00020;
}
.row {
display:table-row; 
}
.row a {
text-decoration:none;
}
.row a:hover {
text-decoration:underline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<h1>This is the header</h1>
</div>
<div id="container2">
<div id="container1">
<div id="col1">
<p>
<span id="table">
<span class="row-header"> News </span>
<span class="row"> <span class="cell"> <a href="http://www.cnn.com/"> CNN </a> </span></span>
<span class="row"> <span class="cell"> <a href="http://www.usatoday.com/"> USA Today </a> </span></span>
</span>
</p>
<p>
<span id="table">
<span class="row-header"> Technology </span>
<span class="row"> <span class="cell"> <a href="http://www.google.com/"> Google </a> </span></span>
<span class="row"> <span class="cell"> <a href="http://www.yahoo.com/"> Yahoo</a> </span></span>
</span>
</p>
</div>
<div id="col2">
<p>
<span id="table">
<span class="row-header"> Stores </span>
<span class="row"> <span class="cell"> <a href="http://www.walmart.com/"> Walmart </a> </span></span>
<span class="row"> <span class="cell"> <a href="http://www.pigglywiggly.com/"> Piggly Wiggly </a> </span></span>
</span>
</p>
<p>
<span id="table">
<span class="row-header"> Games </span>
<span class="row"> <span class="cell"> <a href="http://www.gamespot.com/"> GameSpot </a> </span></span>
</span>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<p>This is the footer</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your width is 100% make it 99%.

```
#table {
display:table;
width:99%;
margin:0;
padding:4px;
border:1px solid #607080;  
background:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Or rather use pixels.

Comment: Right border shows only when 98%. Thanks. The only issue is the markups are not valid (validation by WC3) This is because the id "table" is duplicated. This means if I want to put 20 boxes on the page, I need to declare "table" 20 times to make the markups valid. Is there a more efficient way of making the codes valid?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean here, but perhaps:
<span class="table" id="01"> or div instead of span?

Comment: You are right again, should use "class". The original codes above will generate an error like "An "id" is a unique identifier. Each time this attribute is used in a document it must have a different value. If you are using this attribute as a hook for style sheets it may be more appropriate to use classes (which group elements) than id (which are used to identify exactly one element)." Changing it to "class" will remove the error. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

By default width and height is applied to content. If you specify margin and padding then size of element will be more than you expected.

To change this behavior add "box-sizing: border-box;" to your #table rule and set width to 100%;

Answer (score 0):

You state the following for the header container:
margin-left:2%;
padding-right:2%;

This page gives a good example of what to keep in mind when designing the viewport: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp.

When I viewed the screenshot, my initial thought was that the min-width setting might have been too short to view the other end of the box.

Looking closer at the code, I agree with the others that ids are supposed to have only occurrence in the document. So, you should make it a class. For those of us who weren't taught OOP, some of the concepts take a little longer to sink in until we put them into use for our own purposes. I initially had issues with that and I tried to combine ids with classes to create classes of classes. CSS isn't Java. So, SASS and LESS addressed this shortcoming.

I think you got your SPAN idea from FrontPage coding.